# How to create a Response Object in Node.js/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to do a res.redirect('/signin'), but my res has been used up on a res.render. 
Is there a way I can define a new Response Object (res) in order to perform the redirect?

Comment: Do you want to redirect, or do you want to render a page? Those are two mutually exclusive things, at least from a server-side point of view.

Comment: @roberklep I want to redirect.

Comment: Then don't use `res.render`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you keep the connection open by using write!!, you should be able to add the redirect.  eg.. ->

```
res.render('index', function(err, html) {
  res.write(html);
  res.redirect('/signin');
});
```

Comment: Your answer worked in this simple form, but I am so deep I can’t keep it opened as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation (http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render), If you use res.render it will automatically send the response (unless you pass a callback).

I could not find any way to either create a new res object or to revert res.render call. Regardless, you really should avoid rendering the template if you just want to redirect to another url. It's less work done by the server and the user will be waiting less time.

Comment: I need to do a redirect is so I can router.get this request and open a new signin page, that will eventually return the client back to where they were prior to having to signin.